# Handle back press into the Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

in my fragment i want to setVisibility for one element of my layout on back press.

for example into the fragment i want this:

```
 if(list.getVisibility() == View.GONE){

            list.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            text.setVisibility(View.GONE);

  }
```

But how i can handle the back press event into the fragment? and set this visibility?

UPDATE:

In my FragmentActivity i have:

```
adapter =  new ViewPagerAdapterEventi(getSupportFragmentManager(),Titles,Numboftabs,mE1,mE2);

        // Assigning ViewPager View and setting the adapter
        pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        pager.setAdapter(adapter);

        // Assiging the Sliding Tab Layout View
        tabs = (SlidingTabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabs.setDistributeEvenly(true); // To make the Tabs Fixed set this true, This makes the tabs Space Evenly in Available width

        // Setting Custom Color for the Scroll bar indicator of the Tab View
        tabs.setCustomTabColorizer(new SlidingTabLayout.TabColorizer() {
            @Override
            public int getIndicatorColor(int position) {
                return getResources().getColor(R.color.tabsScrollColor);
            }
        });

        // Setting the ViewPager For the SlidingTabsLayout
        tabs.setViewPager(pager);
```

And into the Adaper:

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

....

 @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {


        if (position == 0) // if the position is 0 we are returning the First tab
        {


            check = position;
            Fragment1 tab1 = new Fragment1();

            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putString("json", mEv1.toString());
            tab1.setArguments(args);




            return tab1;
        } else {
            Fragment2 tab2 = new Fragment2();
            check = position;
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putString("json", mEv2.toString());
            tab2.setArguments(args);
            return tab2;
        }


    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return Titles.get(position);
    }

    // This method return the Number of tabs for the tabs Strip

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return NumbOfTabs;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please override method in FragmentActivity

```
@Override
        public void onBackPressed() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onBackPressed();
            Fragment fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("FRAGMENT_TAG");
            fragment.setUserVisibility();
        }
```

Comment: i can use something like:         adapter.getItem(0).getView().findViewById(R.id.list).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

Comment: yes you can use this method in your setUserVisibility() function of your fragment.e.g.
public void setUserVisibility(){
adapter.getItem(0).getView().findViewById(R.id.list).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)‌​;
}

Comment: i have a FragmentStatePagerAdapter for manage the Fragment..so i haven't the TAG for my fragment..how i can i do that?

Comment: You have dynamic or large number of fragment? If there is three or five tab or fragment then you can create object of each fragment. But if there is large no. of fragment or unknown then scenario will be different.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76628/discussion-between-antonio-balduzzi-and-anand-makwana).

Answer (score 2):

You have to handle this in your Activity

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    MyCustomFragment fragment = (MyCustomFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("TAG_I_USED_WHEN_COMMITTING_FRAGMENT");
    if(fragment != null) {
        fragment.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

And create a public method in MyCustomFragment called `onBackPressed()` to handle everything that should happen when the back button is pressed.

**note:** Don't forget that your `FragmentManager` can also handle the onBackPressed event and remove your fragment from the back stack for example. This depends on how you've added the fragment